# How many functions $f: A \to A$ are there such that $ff = f?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $A = \{a, b, c\}$, then by $|A|^{|A|}$, there are $27$ functions. How do we remove some of the functions that don't abide by $ff = f?$ I am having hard time seeing what we do with $f(f(x)) = f(x).$ How do we show that there is function that doesn't go by this rule?

Comment: Let $B$ be the image of $A$. Then $f$ has to be the identity on $B$, and can have any value in $B$ on the rest of $A\setminus B$. The number, for each $B$, only depends on the size of $B$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $B$ be the image of $A$. Then $f$ has to be the identity on $B$, and can have any value in $B$ for each of the values $A\setminus B$. The number, for each $B$, only depends on the size of $B$.

So this gives:

$$\sum_{k=1}^3\binom{3}{k}k^{3-k}$$

Comment: if $f(A) = B$, then $f(b) = b$ for all $b \in B$. Is that correct? If so, why?

Comment: If $f(a)=b$ then $f(b)=f(f(a))$...

Comment: Are we also saying that if $f$ is identity function on $B$, then there's some surjective $g: B \to A - f(A)$? I don't get why that's true. Sorry, I am just trying to understand your post piece by piece as I am not too good at math.

Comment: I never said anything about a $g$, nor surjections. Given non-empty $B\subset A$, and any map $h:A\setminus  B\to B$, we define $f:A\to A$ as $f(a)=a$ if $a\in B$ and $f(a)=h(a)$ if $a\not\in B$.  This $f$ has $ff=f$, and any such $f$ can be written this way uniquely.